# Clicking contained element also effectively (but wrongly) clicks its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is  [**the problem page I'm developing.**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain)

Consider the leftmost column header, with header text "**Undr**." Here is the simplified html for that column header:

```
<th class="underlying" onclick="toggleColSelect(this);">
    <img class='ad' onclick="toggleColSortOrder(this);">
    Undr
</th>
```

The user can do two things in the column header:

1. select and deselect the column, by clicking the column header. **EDIT:** The column is selected when the column header has a yellow background; and unselected when the column header has a white background.
2. select ascending or descending sort on the column contents, by clicking the up/down-arrow image.

However, clicking the image also selects/deselects the column, which I don't want. When he clicks the image, I want to toggle the sort order only; I don't want to toggle the select on the column.

My JavaScript function `toggleColSortOrder();` does indeed toggle only the sort order; but it seems the function to ***select*** the column also gets called (wrongly) when the user clicks the image.

What I've tried: thinking this might somehow be a manifestation of bubble-up at work, I tried all combinations of returning true, false and nothing in each of the two functions. None of this had any effect. I'd like to avoid hacking the JavaScript any further.

**Question:** how, by changing my html or css, can I prevent the function `toggleColSelect();` being called when the user clicks inside the up/down-arrow image?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem on your site using Chrome. What browser are you using? Oh, and if you want the people who specialize in javascript to respond to this question, make sure you add that tag to this post or it will go unnoticed.

Comment: @Wex -- Thanks! I should have said what constitutes a selected column: it's a yellow background. I added that edit. You'll see (unless I'm crazy) that the problem shows up in Chrome 12.0.742.91.

Comment: @Wex -- You're right, I apologize. The problem doesn't happen in other columns. Sorry about that. Now I'm *really* confused :-) I have been using Firefox.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to say "other _browsers_" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can cancel event-bubbling by adding

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
```

to your functions. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcyCz/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my theory, since your `<img>` tag is INSIDE your `<th>` tag, you cannot click the `<img>` without first 'clicking' through the `<th>`. If there was a way to un-nest these two tags, I would then assume that their functions would be called separately. Possibly using a `<div>` to align your `<img>` over the correct spot. I am going to try to do live adjusting of what I just said using firebug and see (if it doesnt break the javascript) if it works, and I will report back.

Good luck.

Comment: I did try to rework this using firebug, but it broke the javascript function calls and thus I was not able to fully test my theory.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomalak points out, the click event for the `<img>` is bubbling up to the parent `<th>`, and so you must specify otherwise in your function.  Also, add a call to `event.stopPropagation()` for the [browsers which have deprecated cancelBubble](http://help.dottoro.com/ljsgdvke.php).